# Off-topic close reason

Tags: support, flags, allowed-questions

I tried to cast a flag on a off-topic question asking about HDMI and graphics card and I realized that I have no off-topic option to choose.

I don't know why but the only off-topic option to mark was "belongs on meta", and no general off-topic reason.

I don't know if this has it's explanation (low rep or something), but if there is not such an opcion, then this is a feature request. For example, if there is a question asking about cooking cheese?

[image]

Please consider editing the tags if needed.

Comment: Based on your screenshot you clicked "migration" after clicking off-topic.That might be why you couldn't select anything else.

Comment: @Arperum But, there is not general off-topic site. What if the question is about programming?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is currently no way to flag for off-topic that isn't covered by the existing close reasons. This is due to a recent change to the closing system. Users with the [close questions](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/close-questions) privilege can close for a custom (that is, manually entered) off-topic reason instead.